# Where in android can I find my .so?

Tags: android, shared-libraries

I have an apk that use a .so. It was included on it. When I install it in android the .so go somewhere ... I would like to know which directory contain the .so ? I 've searched on android using Shell but unfortunately.

Comment: it goes inside /data/data/youtpackagename/lib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can find it inside `/data/data/youtpackagename/lib`. Please be aware that folder in order to accessible need the root permission